# Magento Catalog_Products Drag and Drop table with jQuery in admin

Tags: jquery, magento, prototypejs

I'm trying to connect jQuery plugin http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/ with Catalog_Products table and I did that. I inject this code(jQuery code) in to grid.js file:

```
...

initGrid : function(){
    if(this.preInitCallback){
        this.preInitCallback(this);
    }
    if($(this.containerId+this.tableSufix)){
        this.rows = $$('#'+this.containerId+this.tableSufix+' tbody tr');
        for (var row=0; row<this.rows.length; row++) {
            if(row%2==0){
                Element.addClassName(this.rows[row], 'even');
            }

            Event.observe(this.rows[row],'mouseover',this.trOnMouseOver);
            Event.observe(this.rows[row],'mouseout',this.trOnMouseOut);
            Event.observe(this.rows[row],'click',this.trOnClick);
            Event.observe(this.rows[row],'dblclick',this.trOnDblClick);

            if(this.initRowCallback){
                try {
                    this.initRowCallback(this, this.rows[row]);
                } catch (e) {
                    if(console) {
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(this.sortVar && this.dirVar){
        var columns = $$('#'+this.containerId+this.tableSufix+' thead a');

        for(var col=0; col<columns.length; col++){
            Event.observe(columns[col],'click',this.thLinkOnClick);
        }
    }
    this.bindFilterFields();
    this.bindFieldsChange();
    if(this.initCallback){
        try {
            this.initCallback(this);
        }
        catch (e) {
            if(console) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    }
    // Drag and drop
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // Initialise the table
        jQuery("#catalog_category_products_table tbody").tableDnD({
            onDrop: function() {
                jQuery("#catalog_category_products_table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
                    jQuery("#catalog_category_products_table tbody tr td input.input-text:eq("+index+")").removeAttr('value');
                    jQuery("#catalog_category_products_table tbody tr td input.input-text:eq("+index+")").attr('value', index + 1);
                });
            }
        });
    });
},
getContainerId : function(){
    return this.containerId;
},

...
```

After drop I do sort function to sort input values like 1,2... this works fine. Problem is that when I save this products new input values are not saving I think this is because magento i using some keypress, change bind function. I will be very thankful for helping me with this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure that it makes sense to include jQuery into admin panel, just to use this component. Magento already has Prototype + Scriptaculous available, you even do not need to enable them. The component that you can use is Sortable, that does all the stuff you need:
http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/sortable-create/

Also it is not a good idea to modify grid.js file, you can easily wrap any class method in prototypejs framework. For this purpose via layout update, you can include your custom JS file that has such a content:

```
varienGrid = Class.create(varienGrid, {
   initGrid: function ($super) {
       $super(); // Calling parent method functionality
       // Doing your customization
   }
});
```

In this case all grid objects instantiated on this page will be calling your custom method code and you are safe with upgradability of your code.

For your particular case the code might look like the following:

```
varienGrid = Class.create(varienGrid, {
   initGrid: function ($super) {
       $super(); // Calling parent method functionality
       var table = $(this.containerId+this.tableSufix);
       this.sortedContainer = table.down('tbody');
       Sortable.create(this.sortedContainer.identify(), {
            tag: 'TR', 
            dropOnEmpty:true, 
            containment: [this.sortedContainer.identify()], 
            constraint: false,
            onChange: this.updateSort.bind(this)
       });
   },
   updateSort: function () 
   {
       var rows = this.sortedContainer.childElements(); // Getting all rows
       for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
           // Check if input is available
           if (rows[i].down('input[type="text"]')) {
               rows[i].down('input[type="text"]').value = i + 1;
               // Updating is changed flag for element
               rows[i].down('input[type="text"]').setHasChanges({});
           }
       }
   }
});
```

Also as for elements, it might be possible that some of them are disabled and not processed. You can debug each element in updateSort method.

Have fun with Magento development!

Comment: Thx very much this is working but sitll I'm not getting this values into database. Can you help mi with that?

Comment: In the last statement I mentioned about disabled elements. Have you tried debugging on it?

Comment: Problem was that this changes where not populated in table. So there where not set as changed.